# Biogrid interaction protein network

Tags: proteins, database, protein-interaction

I need a ppi network for cancer or Alzheimer . 
I'm using BioGrid , In the search field I can specify the gene id only , 
I want to know how can I make an interaction network for one of the disease ? the only condition is the network ought to be huge , 3k 2k proteins .
I had used IntAct , String but none seem to give me what I'm looking for

If not could anyone give me a direct download link of such network